# Why is pre-comit run --all-files -v is not checking Python files

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

This is my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: fix-encoding-pragma
    -   id: check-ast
```

In same directotry I have

```
$ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── main.py
```

When I run `pre-commit run --all-files -v`, from same directory,  I get:

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files -v
Fix python encoding pragma...........................(no files to check)Skipped
- hook id: fix-encoding-pragma
Check python ast.....................................(no files to check)Skipped
- hook id: check-ast
```

I do not understand why file `main.py` is not checked ?
This is my first time using `pre-commit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `main.py` has not been `git add`ed -- that is: it is not part of the repository

`pre-commit` only runs on files which are part of the repository

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit